# Would it be possible to build and arm an aircraft like an F14 or F15 without access to semiconductors while retaining similar capabilities?

Tags: technology, aircraft, air-combat

"Exotic" particle radiation showers my world rendering advanced semiconductors ineffective in carrying out their intended roles in computing. For the purposes of this question the effect is essentially magic.

**Would it be possible to arm and build an aircraft like an F14 or F15 without semiconductors, while maintaining similar combat capabilities?**

Note that combat capability is mainly focused on things like engaging in beyond visual range combat and utilizing a radar to aid in combat and missile guidance. Weapons technology will also follow a similar route since both the F14 and F15 emphasized BVR combat compared to previous generations.

One can utilize things like vacuum tubes, electromechanical computers, analog computers, radio communications, and earlier computer designs systems.

Comment: Seems like you're asking about whether the F-14 had any microchips in it. Is that really a worldbuilding question or a question about a real world airplane?

Comment: AT least an F-15 had a computer and a radar, both are impossible to miniaturize (not craft) without semiconductors. Using lamps would make the plane's electronics brittle, which defeats its purpose as an airplane with high-G maneuverability. So, a definite no. I say the best plane possible without any semiconductors would be MiG-21 or an equivalent.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but then I realized that doing it right takes more time than I have now. The engines and airframe might come close, especially if they can do several generations of wind tunnel tests. The radios and navigation might be adequate, but your F-15 needs a backseater. The radar might have a similar range to early F-15s or F-14s, but it is less comfortable. Again the need for a backseater. The missiles will be the real problem.

Comment: @sphennings Partly yes, and no. I am looking to see if it's possible to build a semi advanced fighter without any semiconductors with significant BVR capability. I'm using an F14 or an F15 because it significantly narrows the scope and makes a question easier to answer. I'm not looking to build an F14 or F15 one to one, but an airframe that has advanced and powerful radar with long range capabilities.  Framing it this way gives a relative target goal

Comment: @o.m. Can missiles be beam guided using semi active radars w/ vacuum tube radar? From some research I've done, a lot of cold war radar used vacuum tube technology.

Comment: @FIRES_ICE, the answer is probably "not nearly as well." In the small volume of a missile seeker, that would matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without semiconductors, you won't be able to build:

- Airborne radars as capable as those of the F-14 and F-15. You can build simpler ones using vacuum tubes, but they are pretty limited. You can't use frequencies above 4GHz or use pulse-doppler techniques. This will limit you to radars for finding aircraft, and for giving the range for firing guns or infra-red missiles. Look-down radars will be ineffective at finding moving targets over land but can work over the sea.
- Effective active- or semi-active radar homing air-to-air missiles. Command-guided surface-to-air missiles were built with vacuum tubes, but they're too big for fighters to carry.
- Your aircraft radios will be much larger and more fragile, and have worse range, security and reliability. The same goes for identification-friend-or-foe systems and infra-red search-and-track systems.
- Your engines will be a little less efficient without a digital engine control system.

Since your example aircraft are stable in flight, it will be possible to make them fly without semiconductors. An F-16, a later design, is deliberately unstable and *requires* a flight-control computer to be flyable.